# MySQL Connector in Python

Tags: python, mysql, timeout, connector

Trying to connect to my MySQL DB on my VPS. I'm getting the following error, when using the below code;

(I've stripped out my credentials  - however I know they work, as I use them for my PHP dev as well.

**CODE**

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
  conn = mysql.connect( user= %USER%
                        ,password=%PW%
                        ,host = %HOST%
                        ,database = %DB%
    )
except mysql.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exists")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
    conn.close()
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%HOST%:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

**Connector That I'm using**

http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.1-py3.4.msi

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual value you are using for "HOST"?

Comment: My website domain, e.g.   www.DOMAIN.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Check the [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) on your MySQL database.  It might be that you haven't been GRANTed permission to connect from that host with the given username and password.

The MySQL error number is 2003.  I usually find it helpful to do a Google search to see if others have had the problem:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Is there a firewall between the client machine and the database server?  I would hope that port 3306 would be blocked by default.  If that's true, you'll need to set up a firewall rule to allow access from the client IP to the database IP via port 3306.

Comment: I've granted all permissions (really secure, i know!) to the user that i'm attempting to use. Still same issue.

Comment: To the user connecting from that host IP?  What did you say about that?

Comment: Not following what you mean there Duffy, sorry. I'm not very good at DB Admin!